# I'm trying to make a piece of code where a user inputs 5 numbers and the code will remove the 5th number. What is wrong with my code?

Tags: python, list, append, typeerror

Here is what I've done so far:

```
def remove_five ():
    list = []
    for x in range(0, 4):
        number = input("Enter a number")
        list.append(number)
    end
    fifth = list[4]
    list.remove(fifth)

remove_five()
```

I get a 'TypeError when I run the program. This is what it says:
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "G:fivealive.py", line 6, in 
    list.append(number)
TypeError: descriptor 'append' requires a 'list' object but received a 'str'

Comment: input() returns a String, append requires a list, isn't it clear enough?

Comment: I don't get that error but your code has a few issues: 1) Make sure your indentation is correct. 2) If you want there to be 5 numbers entered, make the loop "for x in range(0,5)" 3) You don't have to put end at the end of the for loop 4) list only exists in this function, it won't have any effect after the function ends

Comment: What is `end` here? You should not use `list` as variable as it is in-built data-type in Python. And the code you mentioned here is not actual code which gave you that error. May be you had `number = input()` and then you were doing `list.append()` which resulted into this error as value returned by `input()` will be of `str` type

Answer (score 1):

1. Keep indentation correct.
2. `range(0, 4)` will generate 0..3. You want `range(5)`.
3. If you want numbers, convert the input to integers.
4. Delete elements using the `del` operation.
5. Return the created list.
6. Do not use `list` as variable name, as it is built-in type

Fixing it should result like that:

```
def remove_five ():
    my_list = []
    for x in range(5):
        number = int(input("Enter a number"))
        my_list.append(number)
    del my_list[4]
    return my_list 

my_list = remove_five()
```